# Postgresql: создание внешних ключей

Tags: postgresql

Пользуюсь pgadmin4 и не могу понять, как как сделать внешний ключ. Суть в чем, у меня есть две таблицы и надо организовать связь 1:n между ними. Т.е. таблице projects нужно добавить атрибут ссылающий на таблицу user. Пробовал сделать это с помощью Query Tool, со строкой  "user_id integer REFERENCES user," не дает создать таблицу projects.

```
CREATE TABLE public.projects
(
id integer NOT NULL,
name_project character varying(80),
attribute character varying(80),
value character varying(80),
user_id integer REFERENCES user,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE public.projects
OWNER to magic;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы напрасно не написали выводимое сообщение об ошибке. Впрочем одна ошибка бросается в глаза.

Слово `user` является зарезервированным по стандарту, обозначает текущего пользователя СУБД. И потому `REFERENCES user` является синтаксической ошибкой. Для того чтобы использовать это слово как имя объекта необходимо использовать кавычки:

```
user_id integer REFERENCES "user",
```

Либо выбрать другое имя таблицы.

Comment: Действительно, не хватало кавычек, спасибо за ответ)